# failing to populate shadow DOM (following tutorial)

Tags: html, web-component, shadow-dom

I'm playing the the [Shadow DOM 101 tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/) at html5rocks.
I'm using Chrome 25.0.1364.172 and
when I try to `appendChild` to the Shadow DOM root (as shown in the tutorial) I get an
`Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8`.
I guess I'm missing something obvious but I can't figure out what. Here's
the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test the shadow dom</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myName">Alon</div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script id="myNameTemplate" type="text/x-tmpl-template">
            <style>
                .outer {
                    border:2px solid brown;
                    border-radius: 1em;
                    background: red;
                    font-size: 28pt;
                    width: 12em;
                    height:2em;
                    text-align: center;
                }
                .boilerplate {
                    color:white;
                    font-family: sans-serif;
                    padding:0.5em;
                }
                .name {
                    color:black;
                    background: white;
                    font-family: "Marker Felt", cursive;
                    font-size: 45pt;
                    padding-top:0.2em;
                }
            </style>
            <div class="outer">
                <div class="boilerplate">
                    Hi! my name is
                </div>
                <div class="name">
                    alon
                </div>
            </div>
        </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var shadow = document.querySelector("#myName").webkitCreateShadowRoot();
                console.log(shadow);// I get #shadow-root in the console
                var template = $("#myNameTemplate").html();//also tried text(), without jQuery with innerHTML and other options
                console.log(template);//I get the content of the template in the console
                shadow.appendChild(template); //this part breaks
             });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Since my browser doesn't support the new `<template>` tag shown in the tutorial I changed it to `<script type="text/x-tmpl">`.

**Edit:** I get the same error from the console when I try:

```
shadow.appendChild('<div></div>')
Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8
```

Answer (score 3):

`appendChild()` has never worked like that

`document.body.appendChild('<div></div>')` will give you the same error.

What you want is `shadow.innerHTML = template;`

Answer (score 0):

You have got some of the markup wrong and a few lines in the script that select the template are incorrect. I have modified the code so it works.

```
<script id="myNameTemplate" type="text/x-tmpl-template">
...
</script>
```

to this

```
<template id="myNameTemplate">
...
</template>
```

And in your script at the bottom of the page I modified your template var, it was using jQuery for some reason and not `querySelector()`. So this code below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var shadow = document.querySelector("#myName").webkitCreateShadowRoot();
    console.log(shadow);// I get #shadow-root in the console
    var template = $("#myNameTemplate").html();//also tried text(), without jQuery with innerHTML and other options
    console.log(template);//I get the content of the template in the console
    shadow.appendChild(template); //this part breaks
});
```

becomes this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var shadow = document.querySelector("#myName").webkitCreateShadowRoot();
    var template = document.querySelector("#myNameTemplate");
    shadow.appendChild(template.content);
});
```

Here is the complete markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test the shadow dom</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="myName">Alon</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <template id="myNameTemplate">
        <style>
            .outer {
                border:2px solid brown;
                border-radius: 1em;
                background: red;
                font-size: 28pt;
                width: 12em;
                height:2em;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .boilerplate {
                color:white;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                padding:0.5em;
            }
            .name {
                color:black;
                background: white;
                font-family: "Marker Felt", cursive;
                font-size: 45pt;
                padding-top:0.2em;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="boilerplate">
                Hi! my name is
            </div>
            <div class="name">
                alon
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var shadow = document.querySelector("#myName").webkitCreateShadowRoot();
            console.log(shadow);// I get #shadow-root in the console
            var template = document.querySelector("#myNameTemplate");//also tried text(), without jQuery with innerHTML and other options
            console.log(template);//I get the content of the template in the console
            shadow.appendChild(template.content); //this part breaks
         });
    </script>
</body>
```

You cannot use anything other than the `.content` of the template AFAIK because template is  a [Document Fragment](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/) and to access that fragment you are required to select the inner content of the HTML5 element `<template>`.

The way I look at it is that the `<template>` tag is basically a static HTML way of creating a document fragment that you can grab with the javascript method `querySelector()`. You could create the fragment using `createDocumentFragment()` if you wanted to append the DOM through an extension or whatever but that's another bucket of frogs.

Comment: Wow that was so long ago I barely remember the problem